# Why loading external fonts in opera couse window.frames.length to be greater then 0?

Tags: javascript, dom, fonts, opera

On one of the sites I maintain, I've found something like this in the head of page:

```
if (top.frames.length!=0) top.location=self.document.location;
```

It blocks opening of the page in iframe and it works on every browser except Opera (Win7, v. 12.15, build 1748, w32). 
From what I've noticed when I load external fonts in CSS `top.frames.length` bumps up to numer of external fonts I've loaded.

Could you explain why this happens and how precisely opera loads fonts (does this depend on fonts domain or size)?

Thanks in advance!

[edit]

It happens only when fonts are already in cache. Simple test is [here](http://pasjakodowania.pl/test.html).